# cURL command to Java

Tags: java, curl, arguments

I have a cURL command I want to translate in Java

```
curl -H "Key: XXX" -d url=http://www.google.com http://myapi.com/v2/extraction?format=json
```

It works fine.

I started to do in Java: (CODE EDITED, it works)

```
            try {
        // POST
        System.out.println("POSTING");
        URL url = new URL("http://myapi.com/v2/extraction?format=json");
        HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        connection.setDoOutput(true);
        connection.setRequestMethod("POST");
        connection.setRequestProperty("Key", "XXX");
        String data =  "http://www.google.com";
        OutputStreamWriter writer = new OutputStreamWriter(connection.getOutputStream());

        writer.write("url=" +data);
        writer.close();

        int responseCode = connection.getResponseCode();
        System.out.println("\nSending 'POST' request to URL : " + url);
        System.out.println("Post parameters : " + data);
        System.out.println("Response Code : " + responseCode);

        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream()));
        String inputLine;
        StringBuffer response = new StringBuffer();

        while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
            response.append(inputLine);
        }
        in.close();

        System.out.println("REPOSNE" +response.toString());

        if (connection.getResponseCode() == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
            // OK
        } else {
            // Server returned HTTP error code.
        }
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        // ...
        } catch (IOException e) {
        // ...
        }
```

But I don't know how to set my arguments.

Thanks for your help.

Jean

Comment: Which arguments are you mentioning?

Comment: I need to pass -H "Key: XXX" -d url=http://www.google.com to http://myapi.com/v2/extraction?format=json

Comment: is it a header parameter>

Comment: Thanks for you reply. So How I can send these header parameter?

Comment: You can set the header parameters as u set the content type header

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you mean to set a header field `Key` with value `XXX` you can use the `setRequestProperty`

ie

```
conn.setRequestProperty("Key", "XXX");
```

If you want to send data, use

```
String data = "url=http://www.google.com";
conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Length", "" + Integer.toString(data.getBytes().length));
```

EDIT:-

For posting data as form url encoded, try the following code

```
String data  = "url=" + URLEncoder.encode("http://www.google.com", "UTF-8");
conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
wr.write(data.getBytes());
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But how I can send the other parameter? -d url=http://www.google.com

Comment: what do the -d argument mean?

Comment: In my cURL command I am using: curl -H "Key: XXX" -d url=http://www.google.com http://myapi.com/v2/extraction?format=json The API documentation I use is poor. I guess -d means data to send the URL actually. Thanks

Comment: If you mean the data to be sent as the content, i have updated my answer

Comment: Thanks for your help but it doesn't work. I have the same result ("You must give a value"}}) if I do: curl -H "Key: XXX" url=http://www.google.com http://myapi.com/v2/extraction?format=json (without the -d parameter)

Comment: when i executed your curl request, i got error message. I could help more if you can specify which all data your api needs and in which format.

Comment: Actually, I can't provide my private API key. The response I have with my Java code is: Sending 'POST' request to URL : http://myapi.com/v2/extraction?format=json
Post parameters : url=http://www.google.com
Response Code : 400 {"query": {},"errors": {  "status": "400 Bad Request",  "description": "You must give a value"}} it is like -d url=google.com is missing. Thanks

Comment: what type of data is your API expecting?

Comment: As the documentation of curl in linux says "-d, --data DATA     HTTP POST data (H)". The code i provided is doing the same.

Comment: Actually the cURL command works also with: --data-urlencode parameter like curl -H "Key: XXX" --data-urlencode url=http://www.google.com http://myapi.com/v2/extraction?format=json

Comment: Just updated my code, but still doesn't work. Thanks for your help.

Comment: try changing content type as "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"

And you may have to encode the data

Comment: I found a solution, I will edit my code. Thanks anyway for your help!